# How to return HTTP 204 in a Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This seems to be basic but I'm a Ruby/Rails beginner. I need to simply return HTTP 204 in a controller.
Would

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html  
end
```

return a 204?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

```
head :no_content
```

Tested with Rails 3.2.x, 4.x. It causes the controller method to respond with the 204 No Content HTTP status code.

An example of using this inside a controller method named `foobar`:

```
def foobar
  head :no_content
end
```

Answer (score 17):

Look at the [head](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Head.html#method-i-head) method:

> Return a response that has no content (merely headers). The options
>   argument is interpreted to be a hash of header names and values.

Comment: Thanks Michael. head :ok is for HTTP 200 and head :created is for 201, but I couldn't find the argument I should use with head to return a 204.

Comment: I think I found it: head :no_content or head 204. Thanks!

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept the answer by ticking the little mark below the voting arrows so other users know this problem is solved.

Answer (score 14):

If you don't want to render anything at all you can do this:

```
render :nothing => true, :status => 204
```

or like this:

```
render :nothing => true, :status => 204 and return
```

Or you can use the `:status => 204` part with any other render command

Comment: There's an old Rails ticket where this was discouraged, but things might have changed since then: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3499-render-nothing-true-should-set-http-status-204

Comment: @Michael Kohl: Thanks for this link, I wasn't aware of this. As far as I understand it, it's more a matter of style or readable code, and using `head` instead of `render :nothing` should be more explicit, as the [Ruby On Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) explains as well