# What is the preferred way to return an empty JSON response in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, http, rest

When a user POSTs JSON to the /update/ action in a Rails 3 app, what is the best way to respond?

I want to just send an empty JSON response with a 200 code, something like

```
head :no_content
```

or

```
render :nothing => true, :status => 204
```

(examples from [How to return HTTP 204 in a Rails controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592921/how-to-return-http-204-in-a-rails-controller)).

Typically I have been doing this:

```
render :json => {}
```

or

```
render :json => 'ok'
```

Is there preferred or more *Rails-y* way to this?

Comment: you shouldn't return anything with a 204.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

My Rails 3 app uses code such as this for updates. The code for html and xml was auto generated by Rails, so I just added in the JSON renderer using the same format.

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
    format.html { redirect_to(@product, :notice => 'Product was successfully updated.') }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
    format.json { head :ok }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @product.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    format.json { render :json => @product.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Works perfectly, which is what's ultimately important.

Comment: What's the difference between head :no_content and head :ok?

Comment: @Donato a :no_content (204) response is a request that had success but didn't return any content, :ok (200) is a request that had success but that also return the appropriate data.